# Intellisense thinks my symbols are ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, enums, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing my own typesafe enum header-only library at https://bitbucket.org/chopsii/typesafe-enums

The idea is to replace the non-type-safe c-style enum like:

```
enum ItemCategory
{
    BLOCK,
    WEAPON
};
```

with something that's properly type safe.

So far, my solution uses a macro that, for an example equivalent to the above enum, looks like this:

```
TypesafeEnum(ItemCategory,
    (BLOCK)
    (WEAPON)
);
```

And expands to something that looks like this:

```
template<typename InnerType>
class Wrapped {
public:
    InnerType getValue() const { return _val; }

    bool operator<(const Wrapped<InnerType>& rhs) const { ; return _val < rhs._val; }
    bool operator>(const Wrapped<InnerType>& rhs) const { ; return _val > rhs._val; }

    bool operator==(const Wrapped<InnerType>& rhs) const { ; return _val == rhs._val; }


private:
    InnerType _val;
protected:

    explicit Wrapped<InnerType>(const InnerType& val) : _val(val) {}
    void setValue(const InnerType& val) { _val = val; }
};

class WrappedTypeItemCategory : private Wrapped<int>
{
private:
    typedef const std::string* strptr;
    typedef const std::string* const cstrptr;
    explicit WrappedTypeItemCategory(const std::string& label, int val): Wrapped<int>(val), str(&label)
    {}
    cstrptr str;
public:
    static WrappedTypeItemCategory make(const std::string& label, int val)
    {
        return WrappedTypeItemCategory(label, val);
    }
    void operator=(const WrappedTypeItemCategory& rhs)
    {
        ;
        setValue(rhs.getValue());
        const_cast<strptr>(str) = rhs.str;
    }
    int getValue() const
    {
        return Wrapped<int>::getValue();
    }
    const std::string& getString() const
    {
        return *str;
    }
    bool operator<(const WrappedTypeItemCategory & rhs) const
    {
        ;
        return getValue() < rhs.getValue();
    }
    bool operator>(const WrappedTypeItemCategory & rhs) const
    {
        ;
        return getValue() > rhs.getValue();
    }
    bool operator==(const WrappedTypeItemCategory & rhs) const
    {
        ;
        return getValue() == rhs.getValue();
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const WrappedTypeItemCategory& rhs)
    {
        ;
        return os << *rhs.str << "(" << rhs.getValue() << ")";
    }
};
;
namespace {
    template<typename T> class ItemCategoryInner : public TypesafeEnumBase
    {
    public:
        static const WrappedTypeItemCategory BLOCK;
        static const WrappedTypeItemCategory WEAPON;
        static const std::string BLOCKStr;
        static const std::string WEAPONStr;
    };
    template<typename T> const WrappedTypeItemCategory ItemCategoryInner<T>::BLOCK = WrappedTypeItemCategory::make(ItemCategoryInner<T>::BLOCKStr, 0);
    template<typename T> const WrappedTypeItemCategory ItemCategoryInner<T>::WEAPON = WrappedTypeItemCategory::make(ItemCategoryInner<T>::WEAPONStr, 1);
    template<typename T> const std::string ItemCategoryInner<T>::BLOCKStr("ItemCategory::BLOCK");
    template<typename T> const std::string ItemCategoryInner<T>::WEAPONStr("ItemCategory::WEAPON");
    struct ItemCategoryTemplateConstantTrick
    {};
};
class ItemCategory : public ItemCategoryInner<ItemCategoryTemplateConstantTrick>
{
private:
    const WrappedTypeItemCategory* const val;
public:
    class InvalidValueError : public std::runtime_error
    {
    public:
        const int val;
        InvalidValueError(int val): std::runtime_error(std::string("Invalid value given for ") + "ItemCategory::make"), val(val)
        {}
    };
    ItemCategory(const WrappedTypeItemCategory& value): val(&value)
    {}
    void operator=(const ItemCategory& rhs)
    {
        const_cast<const WrappedTypeItemCategory*>(val) = rhs.val;
    }
    static ItemCategory make(const int& val)
    {
        if (val == ItemCategory::BLOCK.getValue()) return ItemCategory(ItemCategory::BLOCK);
        if (val == ItemCategory::WEAPON.getValue()) return ItemCategory(ItemCategory::WEAPON);
        ;
        throw InvalidValueError(val);
    }
    const WrappedTypeItemCategory* const getWrappedValue() const
    {
        return val;
    }
    int getValue() const
    {
        return val->getValue();
    }
    const std::string & getString() const
    {
        return val->getString();
    }
    bool operator<(const ItemCategory& rhs) const
    {
        return *val < *rhs.val;
    }
    bool operator>(const ItemCategory& rhs) const
    {
        return *val > *rhs.val;
    }
    bool operator==(const WrappedTypeItemCategory& rhs) const
    {
        return *val == rhs;
    }
    bool operator!=(const WrappedTypeItemCategory& rhs) const
    {
        return !(*val == rhs);
    }
    bool operator<=(const WrappedTypeItemCategory& rhs) const
    {
        return (*val == rhs || *val < rhs);
    }
    bool operator>=(const WrappedTypeItemCategory& rhs) const
    {
        return (*val == rhs || *val > rhs);
    }
    void print(std::ostream& os) const override
    {
        os << *val;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ItemCategory& rhs)
    {
        rhs.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};
;
```

If I manually pre-expand it, like I have done here - by pre-compiling to file - then intellisense handles it all up until the line that says:

```
class ItemCategory : public ItemCategoryInner<ItemCategoryTemplateConstantTrick>
```

At which point it starts thinking `ItemCategoryInner` and `ItemCategoryTemplateConstantTrick` are ambiguous, along with many other things on every few lines of the file.

The header that contains this code is included in many places. I know I'm violating the One Definition Rule, which is why I'm using the Template Constant Trick, but I think I need to violate the ODR as my goal is to have an easy to use Macro based typesafe replacement for C++ enums.

I'm not sure if it's the violation of ODR that is the cause of my issues, or something else. I tried __declspec(selectany) but it didn't seem to help - and I would prefer if this macro would be eventually cross-platform, because if it works out, I have other projects I would use it in.

Either way, the .cpp files etc that make use of the enum are able to, and intellisense correctly suggests the options.

However, on a possibly related note, if I don't pre-expand the macro, intellisense isn't able to parse it and it doesn't know what a `ItemCategory` is at all, even though it compiles and works fine.

I just want my intellisense to work properly with my typesafe enums - it slows down intellisense and confuses it in other code in the same project.

Comment: Do you really need dozens of enumvalues to demonstrate a point? Could you just show an example with two of those?

Comment: You make a very good point. I'll get a better example shortly.

Comment: Hm, I don't think you can convin ce IntelliSense to work on non-pre-expanded files. It is not a compiler and is easily fooled withlegal but non-conventional constructs.